# How to create a word.docx file after getting document from Sharepoint API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

SP2016 On Prem:

**Utltimate Goal**: Pull files from Sharepoint Document libraries and place onto file server.

I'm using this Sharepoint api to read the data from the file:

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/MyDocLib/myWordDoc.docx')/$value
```

I can download the file data from the api, then manually launch Word and open that file.  It looks perfect.

But now I need to create those files programatically on a file server using visual basic.

It works great when it's a simple text file, but with Word docs I get the error:

> We're sorry. We can't open myWordDoc.docx because we found a problem
>   with its contents.

I've tried 2 methods to create and populate the file:

Method 1:

```
Sub CreateFile(filename As String, newText As String)
        Dim path As String = "c:\temp\" + filename
        Dim sw As StreamWriter
        ' Create or overwrite the file.
        sw = File.AppendText(path)
        sw.WriteLine(newText)
        sw.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Method 2:

```
Sub CreateFile(filename As String, newText As String)
        Dim path As String = "c:\temp\" + filename
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
        Dim info As Byte() = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(newText)
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
        fs.Close()
End Sub
```

I assume I need to encode the text somehow but I don't know what else to try.

**Eventually I need to do this with Excel, ppt and pdf files too so I need something generic.**

If you know of a way to simply grab the files and move them that would be better, but I don't know how I can do that using the sharepoint api.

The `copyto` api can only copy files between sharepoint sites, it can't access the file system.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days I decided to abandon the above approach and do it through the file system instead.

Now I use the Sharepoint api to locate the files that need to be moved, but then use the simple File.Copy method to do the transfer:

```
FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Directory = FSO.GetFolder(ServerShare)
For Each Filename In Directory.Files
     'MsgBox(Filename.Name)
     File.Copy(ServerShare + Filename.name, destinationFolder + Filename.Name, True)
     Debug.Print(Filename.Name + " Copied Sucessfully")
Next
```